# React Native TranslateX to Edge of Screen

Tags: react-native

I need some help determining how to use React Native's Animated view to perform a `translateX` to move the view to the left edge of the screen.

Currently, I have been able to `translateX` with a random number (-50) and the view will move, but I'm unsure how to correctly calculate the distance to move so that the element is right against the left side of the screen.

Ideas?

Comment: How is the component initially positioned? `absolute`ly or with `flex` ?

Comment: @RyanTurnbull its with flex layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually able to solve this by creating another `View` component in front of the component I'm trying to move. Then using `onLayout` of the view to get its width, and finally -`translateX` using the width of the "hidden" `View` component.

Answer (score 0):

If the view you want to move is full width view you can use [Dimensions API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions.html) to get window width and `translateX` the amount of width.